# Odoo 12: Link Redirects broken using Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, odoo-12

Ok, I'm using Odoo 12 on Ubuntu 18.04, nginx/1.14.0 with letsencrypt for my ssl certs.

Most everything is working perfectly, however links from the website that redirect are returning the variable I named in the nginx domain config file instead of using the domain.

```
# Odoo servers
upstream odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
    server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}
# HTTP -> HTTPS
server {
    if ($host = www.qa.moddulu.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = qa.moddulu.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    server_name www.qa.moddulu.com qa.moddulu.com;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://qa.moddulu.com$request_uri;
}
# WWW -> NON WWW
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.qa.moddulu.com;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://qa.moddulu.com$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name qa.moddulu.com;
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;
    # Proxy headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    # SSL parameters
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
return 301 https://qa.moddulu.com$request_uri;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name qa.moddulu.com;
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;
    # Proxy headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    # SSL parameters
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    # log files
    access_log /var/log/nginx/qa.moddulu.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/qa.moddulu.com.error.log;
    # Handle longpoll requests
    location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    }
    # Handle / requests
    location / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }
    # Cache static files
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }
    # Gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.moddulu.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

so, for example, I'm trying to log in and and the url is going to 'https://odoo/web' instead of 'https://qa.moddulu.com/web'.  the 'odoo' in the link changes with whatever the upstream variable for the server is. I haven't been able to find a solution to this.  I've tried rebuilding the server, but that didn't fix the problem.

EDIT:  I am also using google cloud services for my hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I did was to change upstream odoo to upstream qa.moddulu.com.  this fixes the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

It is the bug of odoo12 source code.
Updating it to the newest version solved the problem.